# URL Rewrite working but empty recordset

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my url rewrite is working but it returns empty recordsets...

example.co.uk/pressnote/index?q=4

return to:  example.co.uk/pressnote/index/questions/4.html

it works but doest return my recordset data like example.co.uk/pressnote/index?q=4 does return my datas.

```
my .htaccess:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/questions/([0-9]+?)\.html$ index.php?q=$4
```

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't show your page?

Comment: Are there more rules? Is this some PHP/CMS framework you're using?

Comment: it shows my page but not showing contents of the above query string parameter

Comment: not any cms just pure php

Comment: `$4` should be `$1` … since you have only one capturing group in your regular expression.

Comment: what if i have two regular expression in my capturing group like example.co.uk/pressnote/index?q=4&subject=test  OR example.co.uk/pressnote/index?q=4&subject=7

Answer (score 0):

I simply change `$4` should be `$1`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/questions/([0-9]+?)\.html$ index.php?q=$1
```

Comment: How about having only two capturing group in your regular expression like example.org/b2b/post?post_id=1&post_subject=test to :example.org/b2b/post/1/test